# ASP.NET WEBForms - see steps in real time

Tags: c#, asp.net

Let's assume we have a page with a button.
On button click we have an event function called.

> ```
>     protected void btnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         panelSteps.Visible = true;
>         panelSteps_detailsAboutRecords.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = "dads"});
>         System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000); // WAIT 5 SECONDS
>         panelSteps_detailsAboutRecords.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = "bda" });
>         System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000); // WAIT 5 SECONDS
>         panelSteps_detailsAboutRecords.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = "cdsa" });
>         System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000); // WAIT 5 SECONDS
>         panelSteps_detailsAboutRecords.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = "ddsa" });
>         System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000); // WAIT 5 SECONDS
>         panelSteps_detailsAboutRecords.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = "dase" });
>     }
> ```

In browser we will see the panel only after the entire function is executed.
Why? And how can we see in browser the steps from the function in real time?

Comment: Because the browser will only get the information **after** your method finishes, when the server returns the response. BTW, those 'sleep' are called in the server, so the client will only wait 20 seconds doing nothing.

Comment: Thanks @cFrozenDeath . Is there a solution for my question?

Comment: Have you tried debugging, this is server side stuff, the client side only cares about the final result.

Comment: You can use AJAX / Update panels etc for more dynamic functionality but dependent on what you're actually trying to make, I'd reconsider my approach

Answer (score 0):

You have a client-server architecture where the client is your web browser and the server is where your C# "Server-side" code executes. Your server-side code, listed in your OP, completely finishes and is bundled into a "Response" object before your client sees it.